# ARM template deployment - The request failed due to conflict with a concurrent request error

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-deployment

When re-deploying ARM template with extensions getting error as

```
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "Conflict",
      "message": "The request failed due to conflict with a concurrent request. To resolve it, please refer to https://aka.ms/activitylog to get more details on the conflicting requests."
    }
  ]
}
```

Using Get-AzureRMLog -CorrelationId "xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-Xxxxxx" -DetailedOutput

```
{"error":{"code":"Conflict","message":"The request failed
 due to conflict with a concurrent request. To resolve it, please refer to
 https://aka.ms/activitylog to get more details on the conflicting
 requests."}
```

The deployment name remains same in both iterations of deployment. Have tried changing the name but received the same error.

When I remove Geneva extensions and Anti-Malware extension this error no longer occurs.

Comment: The "arm" tag is for the ARM microprocessor architecture, not for Azure resource manager. Please be more careful with the use of tags.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fill in the `dependsOn []` section for those resources in the `resources` section of your ARM template. In the `Deployments` section of your resource group, you should be able to find out which other resource they are conflicting with and use that information to set the deployment order.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/define-resource-dependency